# Парсеры ломают кодировку

Tags: php, кодировка

Файл в базе хранится вот так: http://pastebin.com/s8ZeyKFS

При выводе в консоль html все символы отображаются нормально.

При парсинге регуляркой тоже. Вот скрин.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но! Как только загружаю в DomDocument, phpQuery, SimpleXML, Nokogiri, то текст ломается, и выводятся непонятные символы!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 $content = html_entity_decode($page['content'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');

 echo $content;//OK

 $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
 $dom->loadHTML($content);

 echo $dom->getElementsByTagName('title')
             ->item(0)->textContent;//BROKEN
```

В чём проблема не могу понять, помогите?

Comment: в какой кодировке файл? приведите код файла, код парсина

Comment: добавил код и содержимое файла

Answer (score 1):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как оказалось, проблема была в консоли Windows, которая неспособна отображать некоторые символы. Даже после активации поддержки UTF-8.